# Why is there an apostrophe followed by "s" in "Miss Sullivan’s having a sister"?

Tags: gerunds, saxon-genitive

In this sentence:

> Cherry had never conceived of **Miss Sullivan’s** having a sister.

Why is there an *’s* right after Miss Sullivan?

Comment: Because _Miss Sullivan_ is the subject of the  gerund _having_, and subjects of gerunds (when they're present -- they're often deleted) may be either possessive (_his, my, Miss Sullivan's_; that's called the `POSS`-_ing_ gerund complementizer), or accusative (objective: _him, me, Miss Sullivan_), which is called the `ACC`-_ing_ gerund complementizer. Both are correct; it's speaker's choice which one to use -- or whether to leave the subject there at all, for that matter.

Comment: Oh I understand! Just realized - what a stupid question I just asked! Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: Not knowing how to ask questions about strange phenomena is normal, and can be found in most of the questions here. No need to insult yourself. Asking the question is the important thing.

Comment: @Sally - But I think the sentence would also work without the apostrophe S.